# Compressing and Serializing QImage over the Network and knowing compressed size in advance

Tags: qt4, image-compression

I am sending Several `MessagePacket` and `ScreenPacket` over the network. but all this packets are followed by a `CommonHeaderPacket` which Tells the type, size, id, time, and checksum of the upcoming packet.  So I need to know the size of Packet before sending.
`ScreenPacket` has a `_image:QImage` (jpeg) which will also be compressed and serialized over the network. I can do this through `QImageWriter` while sending this over the socket. But before sending the `ScreenPacket` I need to send the `CommonHeaderPacket` that includes the `size`. so how can I know the size in advance ? as QImage has no `setQuality()` or `setCompression()` method.
I dont want to write it in a temporary stream to know the size in advance. so what else could be the way to know the size in advance.

### Summary

`QImage` has no `setCompression` or `setQuality` Method. `QImageWriter` has. But I need to know the ByteSize before writing. and byte size depends on the compression and quality.
e.g. I need an `QImage` to be saved into another `Persistent storable Object` with a Change in `Quality`, `Compression`. without Disk Overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it help you to use the `QImageWriter` to write into a `QBuffer`? This way you would avoid the disk overhead and you can access the `QByteArray` to get its size and data to push that directly into your network stream. So you would have to encode the JPEG still only once.